# Summation Function

Tags: statistics

Given the random number

Xi = 2, 4,  6, and 8

Yj = 1, 3,  5, and 7

calculate the following summation function.

My work is below:

x̄=Σx/n=20/4 = 5

Y-bar= Σy/n=16/4=4

Σx = (2+4+6+8)= 20

Σy = (1+3+5+7) = 16

Σxy= (2*1)+(4*3)+(6*5)+(8*7)=100

Σx^2=(2)^2+(4)^2+(6)^2+(6)^2 = 120

Σy^2=(1)^2+(3)^2+(5)^2+(7)^2 = 84

(Σx)^2= (2+4+6+8)^2 = 400

(Σy)^2 = (1+3+5+7)^2 = 256

Σx*Σy = (2+4+6+8) * (1+3+5+7) = 320

Σ(x+y) = [(2+1)+(4+3)+(6+5)+(8+7)] =36

Σ(y-x) = [(1-2)+(3-4)+(5-6)+(7-8)] = -4

Σ(y-x)^2 = [(1-2)^2+(3-4)^2+(5-6)^2+(7-8)^2] = 4

Σ(x-x-bar)(y-y-bar) = (2-1)(1-4)+(4-5)(3-4)+(6-5)(5-4)+(8-5)(7-4) = 20

Σ(x- x̄)^2= 20

Σ(Y-Y-bar)^2= 20

ΣX*Y-2= 92

Σ[X*Y-2]^2=3800

Σ(X*Y-2)^2 / Σ(x-X-bar)^2(y-y-bar)^2

= 3800 / (20) (20) = 3800/400 = 9.5 (9.5 looks like not a correct answer . What am I doing wrong?)

Any help/guide will be greatly appreciated

Comment: You should check your random number generator, it must be out of order.

Comment: Random numbers are given to me. How can I change them?

Comment: You don't need to, but they don't look random.

Comment: Based on this numbers: way my answer is not correct.                              Σ(X*Y-2)^2 / Σ(x-X-bar)^2(y-y-bar)^2

= 3800 / (20) (20) = 3800/400 = 9.5. What I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: (x- x̄)^2
-3^2 =9
-1^2=1
1^2=1
3^2=9
Σ(x- x̄)^2= 20  ?

Comment: What does ΣX*Y-2 mean? Is it x*(y-2) or is it (x*y)-2?

Answer (score 0):

Averages $5$ and $4$.
Equal variances and covariance $5$.
Correlation $1$.
Line equation $y=x-1$.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are talking? My average is 5 and 4. The problem is in here: 

 Σ(X*Y-2)^2 / Σ(x-X-bar)^2(y-y-bar)^2

= 3800 / (20) (20) = 3800/400 = 9.5 (9.5 looks like not a correct answer . What am I doing wrong

Comment: @Saraa In the first place, you should state the question.